# Build unify/normalize data structure from third party API

Tags: design-patterns

This is more of design question. I'm receiving json data structure (big one) from third party API. Now I don't want to take this structure as is and populate it to the different services as is
because the third party API may change the structure (but keep the data).

I want to receive it in one place in my app and build 1 data structure that my services will understand. What design pattern should I use to this central place which receive the third party API? Proxy? Delegator?

Comment: Why do you need a design pattern?

Comment: You just described what a solution would be: "I want to receive it in one place in my app and build 1 data structure that my services will understand.". Why do you need a design pattern name for it?

Comment: make it more organized and extensible

Comment: @user63898 have you already found the answer?

Comment: @Edshav no did not